# Calling method based on run-time type insead of compile-time type

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

In an application, I need .NET to call a method based on its run-time type instead of its compile-time type.

**Simplified Example:**

```
    class A { }

    class B : A { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A b = new B();
        Print(b);
    }

    static void Print(A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called from A");
    }

    static void Print(B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called from B");
    }
```

The above code will actually print `Called from A`, but I need it to be `Called from B`.

This works as expected:

```
static void Print(A a)
{
    var b = a as B;
    if (b != null)
       return Print(b);
    else
       Console.WriteLine("Called from A");
}
```

But for maintainability's sake, it is not desirable.

I believe this question is similar to this one: [Why isn't this method chosen based on the runtime-type of its object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918632/why-isnt-this-method-chosen-based-on-the-runtime-type-of-its-object), but for .NET instead of Java.

Comment: Unless there's a good reason Print is a static member....Print should be an instance member of A&B.  Then you can make the method virtual and override in B to accomplish this task.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I would probably do that if I could, but I can't change them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach if you're using .NET 4 or higher is to use [dynamic typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd264736.aspx):

```
dynamic b = new B();
Print(b);
```

Almost all expressions using a value of type `dynamic` will be invoked dynamically, with a "mini-C# compiler" applying the same rules at execution time as it would have done at compile-time, but using the *actual* execution-time type of those dynamic values. (Expressions whose types are known statically at compile-time will still be regarded as having those types though - it doesn't make *everything* about overload resolution into dynamic.)

If you're not using .NET 4, it's somewhat harder - you could either use reflection, or hard-code the options, neither of which is fun.

Comment: Jon , wouldn't it be better to affect only the dispatch instead of changing the `b` variable ?  eg `Print((dynamic)b);` ?

Comment: @Royi: Why? If you're not using the variable for anything else, what difference do you expect it to make?

Comment: Since he wrote _Simplified Example:_ I assume it _can_ be a situation where `b` is later to be referenced. so I didn't want him to lose intellisense for future usages of _b_. anyway nevermind. for _his exact sample_ it is the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the `dynamic` type:

```
A b = new B();
dynamic tmp = b;
Print(tmp); // Prints "Called from B"
```

However, please note that this has the draw back that it will generate a runtime exception instead of a compile error if there is no matching method.

Answer (score 4):

Use overriding of OOP.

Exmaple:

```
class A { 

    public virtual void Print() { 
          Console.WriteLine("Called from A");
    }      
}

class B : A { 
    public override void Print() { 
          Console.WriteLine("Called from B");
    }  
 }
```

and use it like:

```
    A b = new B();
    Print(b);


    static void Print(A a)
    {
       a.Print(); //will run B's method
    }
```

It will run *runtime* type method, as you use simple overriding concept.

Comment: It works, but in my real-world case I need it to work based on parameters instead of inheritance.

Comment: This, I'd far rather see this than `dynamic`. (But if it's not possible... `:(`)

Comment: @Rawling: But that only works if this method actually can be defined on `A`. There are a lot of scenarios where that is not possible.

Comment: @Meryovi: Then, sorry to say, your real world case is in dire need of refactoring.

Comment: @Ginosaji Sorry, in my case "A" and "B" are a set of POCO classes that I don't own and can't change.

Comment: @Ginosaji: I disagree. There are so many scenarios where those methods can't be added to the type hierarchy or don't even belong there.

Comment: @Meryovi - Are the POCO classes sealed?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey No, but in my case it would be a total overkill to extend them (both) just to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how polymorphism works. You should consider doing something similar to the following instead:

```
class A
{
    virtual string GetString()
    {
        return "Called from A";
    }
}

class B : A
{
    override string GetString()
    {
        return "Called from B";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A b = new B();
    Print(b);
}

static void Print(A a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.GetString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class A
{
    public virtual string Print()
    {
        return "Called from A";
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string  Print()
    {
        return "Called from B";
    }
}
```

And test it elsewhere

```
A b = new B();
MessageBox.Show(b.Print()); //called from B
```